# Different UUID in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Before Swift 2.2 the UUID value was the same every time I opened the app, now changes at every opening

I use this code:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
```

How can I do now to identify the user?

Comment: "Opening"? Did you recompile between to "opening"?

Comment: Why do you need to identify the user? For the specific reasons of privacy, the ability to uniquely identify a device to a user is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually seems to be a bug IMO. Everytime I run my app in the simulator it generates a new Vendor ID. You can probably get round it by storing the ID into NSUserDefaults on the first bootup then retrieving / comparing the value from NSUserDefaults instead of getting it from identifierForVendor. This will save a static vendor id in defaults but in theory the vendor id will still be changing every boot up.

Kind Regards,

Krivvenz.

Update: I can confirm I have installed multiple apps on the same simulator too but the vendor ID is still changing on every boot.

Update 2: - I have logged this as a bug with Apple - 26195931.

Comment: Apparently you are right, the hack of having another app on the device in order to lock the vendor id does not work for me either. Hope this gets fixed, until then this is the workaround ^

Comment: Apple have closed the bug report now saying to upgrade to the latest beta versions of software. (X Code 8 and Swift 3). I installed these from the developer website and the issue is now resolved!

Answer (score 4):

Every time you delete the app, the UUID may change. 
If you just close and open the app, it's should be the same.
But if you delete the app (or install it again via xcode), it might change.

Comment: To be clear, If the app is deleted and reinstalled, the ID is _not guaranteed_ to be the same.

Comment: It may also change from time to time, let's say every one or two years. Same UUID means same user, but same user doesn't guarantee same UUID.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of answers that explain *why* the UUID is resetting.  There's one that offers a *potential* work around, but I'd consider it far from ideal.  But I want to highlight something important about the way UUID's work that serves as a *great* workaround that has **absolutely zero impact** on the production OR debug version of your code base or compiled binary.

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

All you have to do to prevent this value from changing while developing App-A is to simply install App-B from the same vendor (yourself) and keep it installed during the life time of App-A's development.  This is literally as simple as starting a blank new iOS project and install the blank slate to your test device (using the same developer account & such), and then never uninstall it again during development.

App-B keeps a constant UUID for the vendor (yourself) so no matter how many times you delete and reinstall App-A, it will always keep the same UUID.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can
>   also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing
>   an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app
>   stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully
>   handle situations where the identifier changes.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor) for more info.